# Susy and Wordpress - page layout

Tags: wordpress, susy-compass

wordpress returns basically something like this:

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="content"></div>
   <div id="sidebar-primary"></div>
   <div id="sidebar-secondary"></div>
</div>
```

Depending on the layout I chose - I like to have either 1 column full (just the content), 2 columns (content and one sidebar) or three columns with either sidebar-sidebar-content, sidebar-content-sidebar or content-sidebar-sidebar.

does anybody know how to set this up using Susy?
Thank you in advance for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Susy can work with pretty much anything.  The thing with Wordpress is that you need to have a style.css file in the root of your theme directory.

I would just create a new theme.scss file that includes susy and then in your style.scss file include the new theme.scss file you just created.  You'd put all your styles in the theme.scss file.

styles.scss

```
/*!
Theme Name: Your Theme Name
Theme URI: http://domain.com 
Description: Your Theme Description.
Author: Your Name 
Author URI: http://domain.com/ 
Version: 1.0 
*/

@import "compass/reset";
@import "theme";
```

theme.scss

```
@import "susy";
....other styles would go here for your theme
```

config.rb

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"

output_style = :compressed
environment = :development

# Move styles.css up one directory as required by Wordpress
require 'fileutils'
on_stylesheet_saved do |file|
  if File.exists?(file) && File.basename(file) == "style.css"
    puts "Moving: #{file}"
    FileUtils.mv(file, File.dirname(file) + "/../" + File.basename(file))
  end
end
```

I have a compass watch setup on my theme folder so that the compilation of the sass files and movement to style.css happens every time I make a change and save.  This solution assumes you have susy and compass installed.  Good luck!